# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys' has no attribute 'RETURN'

Tags: python

When I run my script it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Development\Python_Project\SDETpythonProject\SDET_Package\my_firstProject.py", line 18, in <module>
    search.send_keys(keys.RETURN)
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys' has no attribute 'RETURN'
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
import time


# this will load googlechrome from the location in C-drive


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://techwithtim.net")
print(driver.title) # print the title of the page

search = driver.find_element_by_name("s")
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
driver.close() # close the browser
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.html

instead of :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
search.send_keys(keys.RETURN)
```

you need to use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```